Cannot define a Show instance
There's something I don't understand. I define a new type Q and based on it, a type alias QPolynomial:
newtype Q = Q Rational
  deriving Eq

type QPolynomial = MP.T Q

instance Show QPolynomial where 
  show x = ...

Then the compilation throws an error: it claims that there's already a Show instance for QPolynomial defined in the MP library by Show a => Show (MP.T a). However my new type Q has no Show instance. So why does Show a => Show (MP.T a) is taken into account?

It doesn't matter whether Q has an instance or not. Haskell doesn't look at the Show a => part of the MP.T instance when determining legality of your new instance.

Aside: please quote the exact error message, it is more helpful than a free prose description.

As an aside, you don't have  new type; you have a new name for the existing type MP.T Q (The relevance here being that even if you did have a Show instance for Q, you couldn't define a separate instance for QPolynomial to "override" the definition for MP.T Q.)

The way I tend to look at it is that "has no Show instance" is a meaningless statement. The compiler has no notion of something not being an instance, all it has is requirements that something should have an instance, and then it starts trying to prove it. It has no way to do the opposite.


So why does Show a => Show (MP.T a) is taken into account?

An instance of the form
-- pseudo-code
instance (context...) => Show (T args...)

intuitively means that a type U which is of the form T args... (for some instantiation of the type variables in args...) satisfies the class constraint Show if and only if the constraints in context... hold (after the type variables there have been instantiated in the same way).
Note that this is an "if and only if" promise that the programmer makes to the compiler, not just an "if". Arguably, the syntax should be <=> instead of =>.
One might wonder why the designers of Haskell did not make this into a simpler "if" instead. The issue here is that, if this were a mere "if", then the compiler resolving a constraint would potentially need to check multiple instances, using a backtracking algorithm. I.e., the compiler would need to check context... and in case of failure backtrack and look for other instances. This can lead to an exponential-time algorithm, though, hence they decided to avoid that.
This is why GHC rejects overlapping instances: any two Show ... instance heads can not have shared instantiations. This prevents, for example,
instance Show a => Show [a] where ...
instance Show [T] where ...

If overlaps are forbidden, GHC can commit to the first (and only) matching instance, completely avoiding backtracking and its exponential blowup.

However my new type Q has no Show instance.

That's correct, but GHC can never assume that negative. GHC aims to perform separate compilation: compiling a .hs file should be possible without having to look the rest of of the program (except for imported dependencies, of course). Because of this, when compiling your module GHC can not assume that other modules do not define a Show Q instance -- indeed, they might do just that!

That being said, GHC allows the programmers to relax these constraints using the somewhat fragile overlapping instances extension. Use with care!
Basically, this enables overlaps such as:
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} context1 => C Int b     where ...
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} context2 => C a   Bool  where ...
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} context3 => C a   [b]   where ...
instance {-# OVERLAPPING  #-} context4 => C Int [Int] where ...

This is more or less what you want in your case, but you must be careful of its fragility. When in presence of multiple overlapping cases (in scope), GHC will choose the best matching case. Note that no backtracking is performed: only a more careful "best case" instance selection is done here, and "best" means "best in scope".
If you follow this path, you need to be sure that your instance Show QPolynomial is always in scope (imported) in all the points of your program where GHC needs to resolve that constraint, so to trump over the more general instance Show a => Show (MP.T a). If the first instance is not in scope, the second one will be taken by GHC.
This priority mechanism is especially fragile in large programs, where we might have both a Show Q instance, enabling instance Show a => Show (MP.T a), and your more specific instance Show QPolynomial. Having both options available could cause GHC to choose the wrong one unexpectedly, e.g., perhaps because the choice was done in some library you did not wrote, where your higher-priority instance was not in scope. Caveat emptor.
